# Styling a vector itself instead of the whole SVG in css

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg that looks like an arrow, the problem is that when I style the svg in css it styles the whole svg (surrounding box) instead of the svg itself (the arrow). So for example if I insert the following:

```html
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #DADADA;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

it will style the box surrounding the arrow & give me this:

[image: svg incorrect styling]

instead of this: 
[image: svg correct styling]

This is my svg code:

```html
<svg class="vector-one" width="96" height="153" viewBox="0 0 96 153" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
      <path d="M92 20.7143L37 72.5L92 124.286L81 145L4 72.5L81 0L92 20.7143Z" fill="white"/>
      </g>
      <defs>
      <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="96" height="153" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
      <feOffset dy="4"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
      </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>

    <svg class="vector-two" width="96" height="153" viewBox="0 0 96 153" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
      <path d="M4 124.286L59 72.5L4 20.7143L15 0L92 72.5L15 145L4 124.286Z" fill="white"/>
      </g>
      <defs>
      <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="96" height="153" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
      <feOffset dy="4"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
      </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: The SVG itself is simply a (bounding) box. It's always rectangular.
Since you're applying the box-shadow to the element, you're applying it to a rectangle (the bounding box).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included all of your CSS, but I am inferring from your screenshot that you aren't going deep enough into the SVG tree to target the necessary element. I am including some code below to show what I mean by going not just to the SVG level, but down into the `g` -> `path` (most SVG code is a little different, so it will always depend on the structure, but that is how yours is structured).

**Please note that not all CSS properties work for SVGs.** You can read which work over at the [the W3 SVG attributes page](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes)

```css
/* Your CSS now (I'm inferring) */
svg.vector-one {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

/* Example CSS to fill the arrow with green color */
svg.vector-two g path {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg class="vector-one" width="96" height="153" viewBox="0 0 96 153" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
  <path d="M92 20.7143L37 72.5L92 124.286L81 145L4 72.5L81 0L92 20.7143Z" fill="white"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
  <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="96" height="153" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
  <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
  <feOffset dy="4"/>
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
  <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
  <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="vector-two" width="96" height="153" viewBox="0 0 96 153" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
  <path d="M4 124.286L59 72.5L4 20.7143L15 0L92 72.5L15 145L4 124.286Z" fill="white"/>
  </g>
  <defs>
  <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0" width="96" height="153" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
  <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
  <feOffset dy="4"/>
  <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
  <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
  <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```